# Why mails from php simple mail form stopped come to GMAIL address

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I've got fairly simple script to send mail messages from site. As website owner told me it was working fine until few days ago it stopped to work. 
Email should come on mail@googleapps.com account. What's interesting when I change delivery address I will get one email and that's it!, after that I can send millions emails and they wont come anymore. Email are not in spam folders. They just stuck somewhere in a limbo!

Hoster have sent me this:

```
Sep 17 12:45:03 pemlinweb448 sendmail[19595]: s8HBj3ri019595: from=r258197@pemlinweb448.hoster.com, size=760, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=201409171145.s8HBj3IM019594@pemlinweb448.hoster.com, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Sep 17 12:45:03 pemlinweb448 sendmail[19594]: s8HBj3IM019594: to=mail@googleapps.com, ctladdr=r258197 (258197/10003), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30510, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s8HBj3ri019595 Message accepted for delivery)
```

This logs say that e-mail was accepted by the recipient mailserver however nowone knows what happend after.

To cut long story short here is the code:

HTML (index.html):

```
  <form name="form1" class="1form" method="post" action="mail.php">

      <input type="text" class="formfields" name="name" id="name" value="" required>
      <label for="name " class="formlabletext">Name</label>

      <input type="text" class="formfields" name="phone" id="phone" value="012345678">
      <label for="phone" class="formlabletext">Tel.</label>

      <input type="email" class="formfields" name="mail" id="mail" value="" required>
      <label for="mail" class="formlabletext">E-mail</label>

      <input name="submitbtn2" class="submits2" type="submit" value="Register!"></div>

  </form>
```

PHP(mail.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['mail'])) {

    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['mail'])) {

    echo "Oops! Fields are empty!";

    } else {
        $name   = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $phone  = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
        $email  = strip_tags($_POST['mail']);
        $subject = 'Some super-duper subject!';

        $message = 'Some Message';

        $to = "mail@googleapps.com";


        $headers =  "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n" .
                "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo " Mail Sent! SUCCESS!"
    };

} else {

    echo " Some ERROR! ";

    };
```

After fiddling around I've found that to overcome this issue I have to send mails with own SMTP rather than from mail@hostsdg4wg.myhostingprovider.com 
So now I have to rewrite whole code for some phpmailer, but this another story.

Another interesting thing is, mails will come if I simplefy the scrip to just

```
$name = "Alex 101";
$mail = "mail@mail.com";
$to   = "mail@googleapps.com";

$headers =  "From: $name <$mail>" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: $mail" . "\r\n";

$message = 'Some Text;

if (mail ( $to, "Test mail", $message, $headers )) {

echo "Sent to $to!";

} else {
    echo "Oops!";
};
```

It just works! I've got every email when I reload the file.
So I don't understand why it worked and then suddenly stopped? And why extended script doesn't work but simplified does?.. mail() unfortunately seems doesn't have any debbuging option, so I don't get any errors therefor I don't know where to start to resolve this mistery.

Perhaps something wrong in my logic?

Look forward for you ideas and suggestions.

Comment: just because something got accepted by the remote server doesn't mean it was actually delivered to the recipient. it can still get marked as spam/junk and get diverted elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But the only way to find out what ahppens there is to speak to someone who administring google servers, which is nearly impossbile in my universe. and again.. simple script sends OK with more logic FAILS. Why google doesn't return any error codes?